# Ivy Mode Swiper key binding not working

Tags: key-bindings, ivy, swiper

I am learning my way around Emacs. I installed Ivy/Counsel recently. I am trying to use search with Swiper but cannot get the key binding to work. I can get it to work with `M-x swiper`. I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is my config:

```lisp
(ivy-mode 1)
(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq ivy-count-format "(%d/%d) ")
(setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-s") 'swiper)
```

I have this as well:

```lisp
(define-key global-map "\C-s" 'swiper)
```

None of the above works. I can still use with `M-x swiper`.

Comment: What does `C-h k C-s` give you? The code you list should work, so there must be something else going on - either the code isn't being evaluated, or the key binding is being overwritten by something else.

Comment: You say "none of the above works". What does that mean - what happens when you press C-s? Does it start an interactive search, or do something else?

Comment: It shows "undefined" when I use C-s and even when I check with C-h k C-s. I'll try a fresh install of counsel. Because in another system kbd works just fine.